# Sorting, Skip and Limit(Skip) queries for Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS Lambda, Amazon DynamoDB and serverless. I have one user table want to do like this.

1. I want to fetch records pagination wise in each page fetch 10 records
   from the user table,
2. I want to make sorting on columns like name and email. This both column with string datatype.

I am using serverless with node.js. Here I'm attaching my serverless.yaml file

```
UserDynamoDbTable:
  Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      -
        AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      -
        AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    TableName: 'user'
```

For sorting i'm trying with this query

```
let params = {
     TableName: 'user',
     limit: 10,
     ScanIndexForward: false
};
dynamoDb.scan(params, (error, result) => { })
```

But I didn't get a response as per my requirement.
Please help me here I'm new into this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`ScanIndexForward` works on range key only. As the table doesn't contain range key (i.e. sort key) defined, the data is not sorted.

> Specifies ascending (true) or descending (false) traversal of the
>   index. DynamoDB returns results reflecting the requested order
>   determined by the range key.

Unfortunately, DynamoDB can't sort the data by any other attributes. It can sort by range key only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we define a multiple Sort key in one table? And how we can write a query for sorting on the particular table? It would be great if you have any example or useful links.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create upto 5 local secondary indexes with different sort keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work around this, the best solution would be to add a secondary global index. That is essentially a copy of your table that has the appropriate sorting keys that come in handy in scenarios such as this.

[Using Global Secondary Indexes in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)